# Is a cascode better current source than current mirror ? Which option is better?

Tags: analog, cmos, current-source, nmos, cascode

I have simulated a cascode and made a M2 in saturation so it will act as a current source. I want to understand which current source is better. Is cascode better because it has a higher output impedance than the current mirror ?

[image]

Comment: Next time please zoom in on the schematic, and maybe put it on a white background if you can.

Comment: Cascode structure has higher output impedance so the current will more constant that mirror. However, the minimum voltage requirement also higher which is a disadvantage. So which is better will depend on the application, low voltage or high voltage and how constant current necessary is.